# Seaborn: reverse cbar

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a Dataframe which represents a binary matrix (0 and 1), with labels on rows and columns. I'm using the following code to print the matrix assigning each label a color:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
N = 100

M = 200
p = 0.8
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], (M,N), p=(p, 1-p)),
                  columns=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:N]),
                  index=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:M]))


cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([(.8, .8, .8, 1.0)] + [plt.cm.jet(i) for i in range(plt.cm.jet.N-1)])

ax = sns.heatmap(df.apply(lambda s: (s.name==s.index)*s*(s.index+1)), mask=df.eq(0), cmap=cmap )
```

[image]

My issue is that the colors displayed in the cbar are in the reversed order with respect to those shown in the figure (and so are the labels). How can I reverse the colors and the labels in the cbar?
I tried:

```
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

but it also changes the structure of the plot.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the colorbar via `ax.collections[0].colorbar` and then call `invert_yaxis()` on its `ax`.

```py
ax.collections[0].colorbar.ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image: inverting the y axis of the colorbar]